# Does combining Shotgun Master skill with Firearm skill give even more power?

Tags: resident-evil-6

What happens if you buy the shotgun master and equip the firearm skill? Does it give it even more power? I've tried it before but I don't see any difference. It either doesn't work or I did something wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the (weapon) damage skills stack according to the author of this popular [Steam guide](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=135778401) (comments).

[image: comment screenshot]

> [...]do any of these skills stack with each other[...]?

author:

> Yes, it should stack accordingly.

Comment: @DGarvanski I used Wayback Machine link because it is not possible to link directly to comments in Steam guides. WM pages don't update. The comments eventually drop from the front and become more and more buried as comments are posted.

Comment: Sorry, thought it was a mistake. If it's better the way it was, you can roll the edit back.